# one html page or multiple for product info?

Tags: javascript, html

I couldn't find anything on this. I have a simple website done in Jquery, CSS and HTML. I have a list of hundreds of products stored in a local folder. Once a product is clicked, the user should be able to see a picture of the specification on another page. The page/pages have the same HTML structure, just name and pictures are different. What is the best way to go about it? Do I create a new HTML for each product? Or should I use the same Html page to render different names and pictures? If so, how does this page determine what product was clicked? Right now I am using href to direct to different html pages, but I dont think this is the optimal way of doing it. If I use a single page to gernerate different content, how do I pass in whats being clicked?

```
<ul id="denison-single-pump-menu" class="container collapse">
                        <div class="row">
                            <li class="active col-md-3"><a style="font-weight:bold;" href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/v10_v20_series.html">V10-V20 Serires</a></li>
                            <li class="col"><a href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/v10.html">V10</a></li>
                            <li class="col"><a href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/v20.html">V20</a></li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <li class="active col-md-3"><a style="font-weight:bold;" href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/v_series.html">V Serires</a></li>
                            <li class="col"><a href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/20V.html/">20V</a></li>
                            <li class="col"><a href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/25V.html/">25V</a></li>
                            <li class="col"><a href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/35V.html/">35V</a></li>
                            <li class="col"><a href="/products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/45V.html/">45V</a></li>
                        </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show some code that you've tried and ask question based on it.

Comment: In addition to the above, what format are your products stored in?

Comment: I dont do anything with the products, just showing a specification of each product. So there are only pdf files for each product stored in local folders. On the product page, there are only 3 buttons you click to show different images.

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow, your question, as it is, is not specific enough. As an example, in your case you could try the single page approach and then, if it doesn't work as expected, you could submit a more specific question, showing what you've tried and asking why it's not working as intended.

Comment: This is a very old website that I am trying to refactor and improve. I can make what I have work. However, since I am relatively new as well, I would like to know the optimal approach when countering problems like this. Do all the online store create a new html page for every page statically? Or do they just create one html page and render different content with it? If so, why are the urls all different?

Comment: Heres what I have thought so far. I can either create a HTML page for every product I have, and have a href that links to the corresponding page. This is the easiest but how would this scale? The second way is to have just one html page that render different products when different link is clicked. I can have a Onclick() or an eventlistener to pass the event to a function that puts content in a blank html and then direct the user to that page. Is this a good approach, is there a better way to pass the event to a new page?

Comment: Hi! Not sure but your question is not clear and the code you included is not helping at all. Maybe you can try to figure out what you really want to achieve and mention codes that you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i will try to solve your problem, you can make modal on the same html page. you can see here how to make modal https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp. to differentiate you can replace the id of the modal and the data-target, by using looping or retrieving unique data from your data ex: id. hopefully this can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. This would work if I wanted the info to show on a small window. But I would like it to direct to a html page where it would render accordingly. My current setup is to have an onlick to pass the name of the product to a js function where it populate that page with the corresponding info then redirect to it.

Comment: maybe you can use javascript window.location.href to get the url and then segment it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679896/javascript-get-url-segment-and-parameter so that it gets a value that you can make into a condition in javascript html purpose that serves to enter the value of the tag. in javascript you can use innerhtml, value, etc. ex: / products/vickers/single%20vane%20pump/20V/model.html/

You can get 20V to be made as a condition value

Comment: thank you so much. I was deciding between using url parameters or local storage to solve the problem of figuring out which item was clicked. Thank you very much.